# I am not getting the JSON data, though it is getting loaded properly, why does that happen so? It is showing blank alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, office365-apps

Following is my code, I want to get the JSON data, I am doing a railway app in office 365 Napa, my JSON is getting loaded but not showing me the data, and I am passing station code that is passed in the string through which HMAC signature is generated by passing it in URL I get the JSON which I have to read,

```
'use strict';

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

(function () {

    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is 
    // needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        getUserName();

        $("#button1").click(function()
        {
            paraupdate();   
        });

    });

    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get 
    // the current users information

    function paraupdate()
    {

        var str=""+$("#textbox1").val();
        alert(""+str);
        var message = str+"json539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3";
        var secret = "<my private key>";        
        var crypto = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, secret).toString();
        alert("crypto answer is " + crypto);
        var siteurl="http://pnrbuddy.com/api/station_by_code/code/"+str+"/format/json/pbapikey/539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3/pbapisign/"+crypto;



        $.getJSON(
          siteurl,
          function(data){

              alert(data.message);

              });

    }


    function getUserName() 
    {
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    // It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
    function onGetUserNameSuccess() 
    {
        $("#label1").html("Enter Station Code : ");
        $("#button1").val("CLICK");

    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }



})();
```

The JSON response is:

```
{
    "response_code": 200,
    "stations": [
        {
            "name": "Kanpur Central",
            "code": "CNB",
            "state": "UP",
            "zip": null,
            "railway_zone": "",
            "location": {
                "lat‌​": "26.4528466",
                "lng": "80.3237478"
            },
            "about_text": null,
            "about_link": null
        },
        {
            "name": "‌​Chandari",
            "code": "CNBI",
            "state": "UP",
            "zip": null,
            "railway_zone": "",
            "location": {
                "la‌​t": "26.4279135",
                "lng": "80.3604594"
            },
            "about_text": null,
            "about_link": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my JSON is getting loaded but not showing me the data"? You seem to have two different Ajax requests there. Which one is failing? How is it failing? Is the error function running instead of the success function? What do your browser developer tools say? Are the errors in the JS Console? Are you seeing the expected HTTP requests and responses in the Net tab?

Comment: Yes there are no errors in my browser console and error function is not running, and that $.getJSON is failing, and not displaying json data, I tried $.ajax but it is still not working.

Comment: And what is that service responding with? It needs keys, so there isn't enough information in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the response from the service, I am passing my private key along with the string which includes the station code, format and public api key, if I put cnb as station code it gives,      {"response_code":200,"stations":[{"name":"Kanpur Central","code":"CNB","state":"UP","zip":null,"railway_zone":"","location":{"lat":"26.4528466","lng":"80.3237478"},"about_text":null,"about_link":null},{"name":"Chandari","code":"CNBI","state":"UP","zip":null,"railway_zone":"","location":{"lat":"26.4279135","lng":"80.3604594"},"about_text":null,"about_link":null}]}

Comment: and it gives the message , " Loading mixed (insecure) active content on a secure page "http://pnrbuddy.com/api/station_by_code/code/cnb/format/json/pbapikey/539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3/pbapisign/906544ca31f9c0048e80bde8127556af828e313b"
 

...tate&&ExpGroupFetchWebPartID(c)!=null&&!Boolean(b.noGroupCollapse))if(e)AddGroup..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to alert `data.message` but your JSON doesn't have a `message` property. Look at properties that actually exist in the data.

> Loading mixed (insecure) active content on a secure page

Don't make Ajax requests to HTTP end points from HTTPS pages. The data isn't secure, can be intercepted and might compromise the security of the page (especially if JSONP gets used for cross-origin requests).

Comment: Oh, sorry that is a silly mistake I made, then it is also not showing me stations property, instead it is showing me Station and station_by_code

Comment: Then How can I access data on an HTTP page from HTTPS page?

Comment: Don't, it breaks the HTTPS security. Find an HTTPS end point for your data instead.

Comment: But that is the only place where I can get Indian railways api which is especially for developers, the pnrbuddy site. Then what would be the solution for this now?

Comment: Proxy the data through your own server (making sure you sanitise it).

Comment: Sorry I didn't got that what should I do actually, means what steps I should follow?

Comment: Make an HTTPS request to your own server. Have your server make an HTTP request to the third party. Parse the response. Convert the parsed data to JSON (so you know it is clean JSON). Return that JSON in the response to the original HTTPS request.

Comment: Sorry sir I know this may be irritating to you but can you show me that how to do it I mean what should I add in my program?

Comment: I tried it in following way but it didn't happened I added url parameter to my url & passed the link,  var siteurl="https://itcubesolutions-43a1b937d5c519.sharepoint.com/RailwayApp/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fitcubesolutions.sharepoint.com&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16.0.2621.1232&SPAppWebUrl=https%3A%2F%2FITCubeSolutions-43a1b937d5c519.sharepoint.com%2FRailwayApp?url=http://pnrbuddy.com/api/station_by_code/code/"+str+"/format/json/pbapikey/539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3/pbapisign/"+crypto;

Comment: Since I am new to all this, How to make HTTPS request to my own server?

Comment: Just use a relative URL.

Comment: What is relative url ? Is that I have to create it?

Comment: I mean to say what changes I have to do in my program?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance its working now see I have written the answer